# How do I find out how many Mongo documents were actually inserted?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def insert_multiple_cakes(cake_list)
  ensure_indexes

  insert_list = cake_list.map { |cake| mongofy_values(cake.to_hash) }

  inserted = db[CAKE_COLLECTION].insert(insert_list, w: 0)

  return inserted.length
end
```

The goal of the function is to insert all cakes from `cake_list` into the Mongo database. Any cake that already exists in the database should be ignored. The function should return the number of cakes inserted, so if `cake_list` contains 5 cakes and 2 of those cakes already exist in the database, the function should return 3.

My problem is that after an hour of experimenting, I have concluded the following:

- If the write concern (the `:w` option) is 0, then the insert call silently ignores all duplicate inserts, and the return value contains *all* the input documents, even those that weren't inserted. It doesn't matter what I set `:continue_on_error` or `:collect_on_error`, the return value *always* contains all the documents, and the list of collected errors is always empty.
- If the write concern is 1, then the insert call fails with an `Mongo::OperationFailure` if there are any duplicates among the input documents. It doesn't matter what I set `:continue_on_error` or `:collect_on_error` to, the insert always fails when there are duplicates.

So it seems to me that the only way to achieve this is to iterate over the input list, perform a search for EVERY document and filter away those that already exist. My application is going to deal with (at least) thousands of inserts at a time, so I like this plan about as much as I'd like to jump off a bridge.

Have I misunderstood something, or is the Ruby client perhaps bugged?

---

To demonstrate, this function does exactly what I want and works:

```
def insert_multiple_cakes(cake_list)
  ensure_indexes

  collection = db[CAKE_COLLECTION]

  # Filters away any cakes that already exists in the database.
  filtered_list = cake_list.reject { |cake|
    collection.count(query: {"name" => cake.name}) == 1
  }

  insert_list = filtered_list.map { |cake| mongofy_values(cake.to_hash) }

  inserted = collection.insert(insert_list)

  return inserted.length
end
```

The problem is that it performs about a gazillion searches where it should only really have to do one insert.

---

[Documentation for `Mongo::Collection#insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.9.2/Mongo/Collection.html#insert-instance_method)

Comment: Check out the bulk API: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Bulk-Write-Operations

Comment: A Write Concern of `w:0` does exactly as advertised. There is no result given. This is "fire and forget" so you are basically telling the server to "not tell you" what happened. Bulk operations give you more information, but not for a `w:0` so @ranman is not correct in this being of help. As long as you get an "ackknowledgement" your code works. You are using the service in the wrong way for the result you expect.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Ok, so how do I use the service in the right way for the result I expect?

Comment: His issue isn't with the write concern, his issue is with knowing how many new items he added. In this case the bulk API is perfect.

Comment: Any other [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) response that actually gives a response. `{w:1}` is a basic start. By asking for `{w:0}` you are explicitly asking the server to **not respond**. Understand?

Comment: @ranman Completely wrong. The Write Concern is the issue here. The Bulk API issued with the same write concern arguments issues no response in exactly the same way.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Out of curiosity, have you read my question? At no point have I said that I *need* to use `{w: 0}`, I have only said that the only way to avoid a raised exception from `insert` is to set it to 0. Also out of curiosity, if setting `:w` to `0` tells the server *not* to respond, how come the `insert` returns the ID of all inserted documents?

Comment: @Hubro Out of curiosity have you checked out my profile? Guessing that you have not. Not the guy you need to question on "Do I understand what you are asking?" The **one** thing that is **true** of the Bulk API is you can use `UnOrderedOp` to essentially "skip" errors and just keep inserting. I suppose my overall point here was an "answer" didn't seem warranted since you asked for "fire and forget". In hindsight, maybe an answer should have been given to explain in full.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Then how come you're fixated on the write concern? In my question I said that I've experimented with setting it to 0 and 1, neither of which produced a result I could use. All I'm trying to do is perform an insert that ignores duplicates, and reports how many documents were *actually* inserted. Again, I'm not trying to be rude, I'm just wondering.

Comment: @NeilLunn I believe you've misread the question. His goal is plainly stated "The goal of the function is to insert all cakes from cake_list into the Mongo database. Any cake that already exists in the database should be ignored. The function should return the number of cakes inserted, so if cake_list contains 5 cakes and 2 of those cakes already exist in the database, the function should return 3." this is easily achievable through the bulk API as I have outlined below.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I'm not asking for "fire and forget", I'm asking for "ignore duplicates and get the amount of inserted documents". If I can do that with a safe write concern, all the better.

Comment: @ranman gave you a correct way to do this. But the point still remains you cannot set the write concern to `0` which is what "fire and forget" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this ([source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Bulk-Write-Operations)):

```
coll = MongoClient.new().db('test').collection('cakes')
  bulk = coll.initialize_unordered_bulk_op
  bulk.insert({'_id' => "strawberry"})
  bulk.insert({'_id' => "strawberry"}) # duplicate key
  bulk.insert({'_id' => "chocolate"})
  bulk.insert({'_id' => "chocolate"}) # duplicate key
begin
  bulk.execute({:w => 1}) # this is the default but don't change it to 0 or you won't get the errors
rescue => ex
  p ex
  p ex.result
end
```

`ex.result` contains `ninserted` and the reason each one failed.

```
{"ok"=>1,
 "n"=>2,
 "code"=>65,
 "errmsg"=>"batch item errors occurred",
 "nInserted"=>2,
 "writeErrors"=>
  [{"index"=>1,
    "code"=>11000,
    "errmsg"=>
     "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.cakes.$_id_  dup key: { : \"strawberry\" }"},
   {"index"=>3,
    "code"=>11000,
    "errmsg"=>
     "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.cakes.$_id_  dup key: { : \"chocolate\" }"}]}
```

Comment: "Unordered Op" is basically the key here since it skips errors and just reports them by definition. But you can still pass a `{w:0}` write concern in here and not get the error reports. Which was my point. But +1 for a correct approach.

Comment: Yup, updated my answer to reflect that. Also, I definitely understand writeconcern I just didn't understand why you were brining it up for this question (though now I do) -- I worked at mongodb for many years :). It's always awesome to find passionate mongodb fans.

Comment: So what actually happens when you run `insert` with an array of documents? Does the Ruby Mongo driver just do one insert at a time?

Comment: @Hubro No it actually submits all in a "batch" but in a "legacy" way. The Bulk Operations API is the way forward, since there is a better response given than was available to the legacy API. So yes, us "fans" (/contributors) really wanted the better responses that the Bulk API gives. Write concern is still something we want everyone to understand the usage of though.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk operations was the way to go. I'm accepting ranman's answer, but I thought I should share my final code:

```
def insert_documents(collection_name, documents)
  collection = db[collection_name]

  bulk = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op
  inserts = 0

  documents.each { |doc|
    bulk.insert doc

    inserts += 1
  }

  begin
    bulk.execute
  rescue Mongo::BulkWriteError => e
    inserts = e.result["nInserted"]
  end

  return inserts
end

def insert_cakes(cakes)
  ensure_cake_indexes

  doc_list = cakes.map { |cake|
    mongofy_values(cake.to_hash)
  }

  return insert_documents(CAKE_COLLECTION, doc_list)
end
```